# Calculating power consumption by a cipher program

Tags: encryption

When a block cipher program is run it consumes some power, how that can be calculated using software aspects? Is there any way to prove a cipher a lightweight cipher without using hardware parts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with cryptography. Implementations of encryption schemes are no different than other programs, and the question has no ties to side-channels, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If any program is run it consumes some power. There is no way to programmatically calculate the power consumption for a given cryptographic primitive, because this not only depend on how you implemented said primitive but also on the hardware (mostly CPU) used. The best thing you can have is to measure the time it took to calculate the primitive.

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends, but for a lot of algorithms benchmarks are run, which show the number of cycles per byte. If the cycles per byte are low for a particular platform it could be considered light weight when it comes to execution of the cipher on a CPU.

Mind that a lightweight cipher may also be optimized for implementation size and size of the (intermediate) state - in other words: memory and cache usage. Fortunately the amount of input / output is *not* an issue as this will simply consist of the plaintext and ciphertext.

Power usage will be related to the amount of cycles per byte. However, some instructions may take more power than others and cache misses may be expensive as well. These variables would be extremely hard to calculate without knowing the specifics of a CPU.

And even if they are known: the CPU could start throttling when specific temperatures are met. This could influence the results.

Generally it will be easier to simply *measure* the power usage rather than to calculate it.